# Android JobScheduler. Can I schedule job every 15 seconds

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

My code is work. But I'm not sure that this will work on all devices and always.
Can I use JobScheduler like this?

Start method:

```
public static void schedule() {
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

    JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(1, new ComponentName(context, MySchedulerService.class))
            .setMinimumLatency(15000)
            .build();

    scheduler.schedule(job);
}
```

Service:

```
public static class MySchedulerService extends JobService {

    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        schedule();
       /*   Business code   */
        stopSelf();
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I schedule job every 15 seconds

No. Minimum duration between two schedule is around 15 minutes. You can easily query for this information using [getMinPeriodMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo#getMinPeriodMillis())

> **Note:**
>
> Attempting to declare a smaller period that this when scheduling a job
>   will result in a job that is still periodic, but will run with this
>   effective period.

For `setMinimumLatency`, based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#setMinimumLatency(long)):

> Milliseconds before which this job will not be considered for
>   execution.

This doesn't mean the job will be executed immediately after 15 seconds and won't be reliable from Android N when [first phase of doze](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#doze) mode kicks in.

Comment: I know it. Therefore, I used this hack. I start a new task every time. The question is, is it reliable?

Comment: I think it's work whet you try to set period more than 15 minutes. But in my case, I schedule new task.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,It is really informative for me. About setMinimumLatency, it's does't matter in my case, if doze don't kills the task completely.

Comment: @DmitriyKholin no problem. Doze mode will defer the Job and won't kill it. Its just won't guarantee that your Job will be executed every 15 seconds. If you feel answer was helpful, remember to mark as accepted, so that others can benefit too.