# My work manager is not working after kill the application

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My android application doesn't run the workmanager when I killed the application.
The workmanager stop working when the application process killed.

my code is :

```
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .build();
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(workRequest);
```

and I have also applied `Jobscheduler` but the program is working when application still alive in the process. but when the application closed the workmanager is not working. I have set the periodic time is `1 min`.

Comment: What constraints did you set?

Answer (score 2):

The minimum interval for PeriodicWork is 15 minutes.
Can you change the interval to 15 and check.
Please check

https://medium.com/@yonatanvlevin/the-minimum-interval-for-periodicwork-is-15-minutes-same-as-jobscheduler-periodic-job-eb2d63716d1f

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51074388/2131915

Comment: I have the same issue, i have given 18 minute but issue is the remain same

Comment: or you wanna say that wait for 15 minutes and then check

Comment: no issue is remain same here. Its only run only one time when application is alive. when i close the application the workmanager not working

Comment: Mr. Raghu your answer was most appreciate able, i found the solution with your answer. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The workmanager DOES NOT stop working when the application process killed, you set the period to 1 minute and minimum is 15 minute, so workmanager does the work you specified every 15 minute instead of 1 minute and ignore that 1 minute!